# iCloud Drive, please don't download this folder on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, data-synchronization

so far I have used iCloud for one text app sync between my MacOS and iOS. Yesterday I added a 4GB folder to iCloud drive so I can access these files on Windows. But of course my iPhone started downloading the folder as well. Now it has only 200MB of free space and constantly reboots/springs (or whatever that is) and is pretty much unusable.

I know that with time iOS will delete its local copy of said folder to free up space. But I can't wait, and those large files change all the time so it will endlessly download them again.

**Is there any way on iOS to say: Download this folder only on demand?** People with 200GB plans must have a way not to run into this with their phones, right?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open Files
- Long-press on the file/folder in question
- Select "Remove Download" (first entry in menu)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'm stuck on iOS 15 and there is no "Remove download". The top choice is "information" (translated from German), the bottom one "delete". Neither offer an option to delete the download without deleting from my Mac as well. Could this option be somewhere else on iOS 15?

Comment: @kim Could be, but I have no iOS 15 device to play around with. Did you verify with a test file that „delete“ actually deletes all copies?

Comment: Yes I did. And searching for "remove download" tells me that [it was not possible on iOS 15 / in June 2022](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253566869).